# How can I test my asp.net web API method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api method:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("GET")]
        public string Get(string apiKey, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == apiKey);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            var records = db.Histories.Where(h => h.Date >= start && h.Date <= end);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records);
        }
```

And here is the url I tried to call the method, but it doesn't reach to the method.

```
http://localhost:11847/api/History/Get?apiKey=398cfa9b-8c5c-4cf4-b4f3-8904a827ff22&start=2014-01-01&end=2014-12-01
```

I also have changed the WebApiConfig.cs

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

from "api/{controller}/{id} to "api/{controller}/{action}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE 2022:
It's 2022 now. A lot has changed. There are plenty of clients out there. I will list my favourites.

1. Postman - Postman has improved since I answered this in 2014. Apart from being a client, it has other features like collaboration, scripting, importing endpoints from various sources like Open API etc. Pretty simple to use.
2. Thunder Client - A Visual Studio extension that has a similar feel as Postman but a pure API client.

---

For testing the api, you can use fiddler(http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or a chrome app called postman.

[image]

You should also try the POSTMAN by http://www.getpostman.com/ which can be added to chrome as an app. It really good and lets you organize your apis.

Comment: I'm using Fiddler. I just don't know how to write the url in the Fiddler

Comment: How to write the url in Fiddler?

Comment: If fiddler is overwhelming use Chromes app POSTMAN which I use. It's simple and easy.

Comment: +1 for  POSTMAN. It is very good tool for testing the methods

Comment: Hi DanKodi, I reviewed my question and your answer and found that your post answers my question(while mine only answers the my question in the comment). So I marked yours as my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to write the url in Fiddler:

In the Composer panel:

```
Parsed:
GET : http://localhost:11847/api/History/GetRecords?apiKey=398cfa9b-8c5c-4cf4-b4f3-8904a827ff22&start=2014-01-01&end=2014-12-01

Request Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:11847
Content-Length: 0
```